# Stop animation started by $animate.addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

Is there a way to stop an animation initiated by $animate.addClass?

```js
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").directive("stopAnimation", function($animate) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        
        // Start animation
        scope.$applyAsync(function() {
          var promise = $animate.addClass(element, "is-visible");
          
          // Stop animation
          setTimeout(function() {
            $animate.cancel(promise);
          }, 100);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.header.is-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.header.is-visible {
  transition: transform 3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header" stop-animation></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this demo the animation should be stopped after 100ms, since the promise was canceled. However, it finishes as normal. What I want to achieve is stopping the animation and make it jump immediately to it's final state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you can use `$animate.setClass`. Remove your `is-visible` class and add new css which hasn't transition.

```js
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").directive("stopAnimation", function($animate) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        
        scope.forceCancel = function(){
          $animate.setClass(element, "is-visible-stopped","is-visible");
        }
        // Start animation
        scope.$applyAsync(function() {
          var promise = $animate.addClass(element, "is-visible");
          
          // Stop animation
          setTimeout(function() {
            $animate.cancel(promise);
          }, 100);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.header.is-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.header.is-visible {
  transition: transform 3s;
}

.header.is-visible-stopped {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header" stop-animation> <button style="margin-top:60px" ng-click="forceCancel()"> Cancel</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it with changing `.is-visible`'s transition to none. And after setTimeout function, you can add it again.

```
// Stop animation
setTimeout(function() {
        $(".is-visible").css("transition","none");
      }, 100);
 }
```